# Save reference to Lua's userdata

Tags: c, lua, lua-userdata

#1 Lua:

```
local test = Test();
```

#2 C:

```
//creating "lua's test"
luaL_newmetatable(L, "someTable");
lua_userdata *userData = (lua_userdata *)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(lua_userdata));

luaL_getmetatable(L, "someTable");
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
```

#3 Lua:

```
function test.newMethod()
end
```

#4 C:

```
//this part is not executed from Lua
//what i have to have here from #2 to call "test.newMethod" and how to call it?
//if userdata would be on stack i guess i could:
luaL_getmetafield (L, 1, "newMethod");
lua_call(L, 0, 0);
//but because this part is not executed by Lua call its not on stack.
```

Edited:

will try to explain simpler in pseudo code:

Lua:

```
local test = Object();
```

C:

```
int Object(){ 
    ... 
    somePointer = luaL_newmetatable(...); //how to get this "somePointer"? maybe luaL_ref?
    push ... 
}
```

Lua: makes new method

```
function test.newMethod() 
    ... 
end
```

In C some event (lets say timer) triggers C method

```
void triggeredCMethod(){ 
    //here i need to call test.newMethod 
    //if i would have here 'somePointer' and could push it to Lua stack i could find and call newMethod 
}
```

so question is: how in C store pointer to some Lua object (hope i need that), get Lua object by that pointer and call method in it

Comment: Let me see if I have this right.  You have a function defined in Lua, and you'd like to pass to it a userdata argument that you created in C.  Some arbitrary amount of time might pass between when you create that userdata and when you need to use it, so you can't just push it onto the Lua stack as soon as it's created.  Accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to be able to call dynamically added functions. This code should explain it relatively simply. Note I don't do much error checking and make a few assumptions, don't copy paste this as a solution.

```
typedef struct
{
    int number;
    int reference;
    lua_State *L;
} TestUserdata;

static int m_newindex( lua_State *L )
{
    /* This is passed three values, first ( at -3 ) is the object, bring this to the front */
    lua_getfenv( L, -3 );
    /* Now bring the second arg forward, the key */
    lua_pushvalue( L, -3 );
    /* And the third arg, the value */
    lua_pushvalue( L, -3 );
    /* And we're done */
    lua_rawset( L, -3 );

    return 0;
}

static int m_tostring( lua_State *L )
{
    lua_pushstring( L, "TestUserdata" );
    return 1;
}

static int callobject( lua_State *L )
{
    /* Grab the object passed, check it's the right type */
    TestUserdata *data = luaL_checkudata( L, 1, "TestUserdata" );

    /* Grab the function environment we gave it in createobject, and look in there for newmethod */
    lua_getfenv( L, -1 );
    lua_pushstring( L, "newmethod" );
    lua_rawget( L, -2 );

    /* Call the function */
    lua_pushinteger( L, data->number );
    lua_call( L, 1, 0 );

    return 0;
}

static const struct luaL_reg userdata_m[] = {
    { "__newindex", m_newindex },
    { "__tostring", m_tostring },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs( L );

    /* Let's create us a userdatum metatable, and fill it up with goodies */
    luaL_newmetatable( L, "TestUserdata" );
    /* Use luaL_register to fill up the metatable for us */
    luaL_register( L, NULL, userdata_m );
    lua_pop( L, 1 ); /* Clean up the stack, we won't need the metatable left here */

    TestUserdata *data = lua_newuserdata( L, sizeof( TestUserdata ) );
    lua_pushvalue( L, -1 ); /* Copy for luaL_ref */
    int ref = luaL_ref( L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX );
    data->reference = ref;
    data->number = 42;
    data->L = L;

    /* Load the metatable from before and 'give' it to this userdatum */
    luaL_getmetatable( L, "TestUserdata" );
    lua_setmetatable( L, -2 );

    /* Give this object an empty function environment */
    lua_newtable( L );
    lua_setfenv( L, -2 );

    lua_setglobal( L, "test" );

    luaL_dostring( L, "function test.newmethod( num ) print( num ) end" );

    /* Now provided we have the object, we can call any method defined anywhere */
    lua_rawgeti( data->L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, data->reference );
    lua_getfenv( data->L, -1 );
    lua_pushstring( data->L, "newmethod" );
    lua_rawget( data->L, -2 );
    lua_remove( data->L, -2 );

    if( lua_isfunction( data->L, -1 ) == 1 )
    {
        lua_pushinteger( data->L, data->number );

        lua_pcall( data->L, 1, 0, 0 );
    }

    lua_close( L );

    return 0;
}
```

Check that, I think that's what you're after.

Comment: the problem with your solution is that you calling "callobject( test )" from Lua. Doing so you getting everything you need onto Lua stack.
How to do same call not from Lua? Basically my question was how to pass that "test" object not from Lua.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to call the Lua function `test.newMethod()', then I think you want something on the order of this:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "test");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "newMethod");
lua_call(L, 0, 0);
```

I don't think you need to mess with a metatable or a userdata.

However the force of your question is not entirely clear to me...